# Type Mismatch Null value SQL

Tags: sql, types, rdbms, create-table, mismatch

I'm having a problem with Null values in my CREATE TABLE for some reason...It's giving me this error message:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 73
>       Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 7 (Manager).

Here's my code and the data I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE SalesReps
(
    EmpNum      SMALLINT    NOT NULL    ,
    Name        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Age         TINYINT     NOT NULL,
    RepOffice   TINYINT     NULL,
    Title       VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    HireDate    DATE,
    Manager     INT         NULL,
    Quota       MONEY       NULL,
    Sales       MONEY       DEFAULT 0
)

BULK INSERT SalesReps
FROM 'C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\salesreps.txt'
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
       ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Data:

```
105|Bill Adams|37|13|Sales Rep|02/12/88|104|350000.00|367911.00
109|Mary Jones|31|11|Sales Rep|10/12/89|106|300000.00|392725.00
102|Sue Smith|48|21|Sales Rep|12/10/86|108|350000.00|474050.00
106|Sam Clark|52|11|VP Sales|06/14/88|NULL|275000.00|299912.00
104|Bob Smith|33|12|Sales Mgr|05/19/87|106|200000.00|142594.00
101|Dan Roberts|45|12|Sales Rep|10/20/86|104|300000.00|305673.00
110|Tom Snyder|41|NULL|Sales Rep|01/13/90|101|NULL|75985.00
108|Larry Fitch|62|21|Sales Mgr|10/12/89|106|350000.00|361865.00
103|Paul Cruz|29|12|Sales Rep|03/01/87|104|275000.00|286775.00
107|Nancy Angelli|49|22|Sales Rep|11/14/88|108|300000.00|186042.00
```

Can anyone please help? I've looked at the other mismatch pages but they aren't helping much. I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: I think you just need to remove all NULL values from the file: "110|Tom Snyder|41||Sales Rep|01/13/90|101||75985.00". I suppose they are treated as common strings

Comment: the string value NULL (having nothing to do with the db value NULL) cannot be converted into an integer.  Its these values that are likely hanging up your bulk import.

Comment: Please tag RDBMS. You should have seen [a pop up](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/73226) already reminding you of this when asking.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk insert on row 4 includes a value NULL, but I think that SQL Server interprets this as string containing 'NULL'. You can try to change row 4 with that :

```
106|Sam Clark|52|11|VP Sales|06/14/88||275000.00|299912.00
```

You will also have the same problem on row 7, your column `Quota` which expects a MONEY type, but a string containing NULL is provided.

Comment: I generated a CSV file using this tutorial and by default SQL will write "NULL" instead of an empty string. There has to be a better solution than manually changing the output CSV file, without having to spam ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, columnName), '') in the select statement: 
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/waterox-sql/2014/08/19/export-a-ssms-query-result-set-to-csv/